# Receiving consecutive SEND intents brings app back to the front, but does not update Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

On a project I'm working on I've come across an issue with receiving external intents, i.e. non-launcher intents. I have an `Activity` that can be started using the normal `LAUNCHER` intent, but it also responds to `SEND` intents from other apps, e.g. sharing a link to a video in the YouTube app. The first time I'm sharing a link from the other app, my `Activity` is created and I can use `getIntent()` to get at the details of the intent, i.e. the `EXTRA_TEXT`. If I close my `Activity` and try again with another link, that works fine too. However, if I don't close my `Activity`, go back to the other app via "home" or "recently launched apps", and share another link, my `Activity` comes back to the foreground, but `getIntent()` results in the *old* intent, not the new one that I would have thought triggered the restart of my `Activity`.

I have created an MCVE illustrating this issue:

The `Activity`:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    private TextView tv;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.d("MainActivity", "onCreate");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.intent_text);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        Log.d("MainActivity", "onResume");
        super.onResume();
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String text;
        if (intent.hasExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT)) {
            text = intent.getExtras().getString(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);
        } else {
            text = "nothing";
        }
        tv.setText(text);
    }
}
```

The manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.intenttest"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="IntentTest"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="IntentTest" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="text/*" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

For completeness sake, the trivial layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.intenttest.MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/intent_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

1. Start app, text view prints "nothing"
2. Start YouTube app, share link, select this app, app gets restarted, text view shows whatever text YouTube has shared
3. Press home
4. Back to YouTube app, share different link, select this app, app gets restarted, text view shows same old text from before
5. Press back or swipe app from "recent apps"
6. Back to YouTube app, share yet another link, select this app, app gets restarted (re-created), text view shows new text YouTube has just shared

I get the feeling I'm missing something fundamental here. How do I get my app to respond to the new `Intent`?

Comment: try this override before oncreate: @Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
   
    setIntent(intent);
}

Comment: `onNewIntent()` will only be called if the activity is set to `android:launchMode="singleTop"` as David Wasser describes in his answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `android:launchMode="singleTop"` to the `<activity>` description.

When the Activity is launched (if it isn't already running), Android will call `onCreate()` and you can get the `Intent` by calling `getIntent()` (like you are already doing).

If the Activity is launched while your app is already running, Android will bring it to the foreground and will call `onNewIntent()` passing in the new `Intent`. You should override this method and do something with the passed `Intent` (save it in a member variable or extract what you want from it or whatever). After that Android will call `onResume()`.

Calling `getIntent()` will ALWAYS return the `Intent` that was used to originally start the Activity.

Comment: While this answers the question, I have to say I am a bit confused. According to http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html "Every time there's a new intent for a "standard" activity, a new instance of the class is created to respond to that intent. Each instance handles a single intent." So if I do _not_ want my activity to be singleTop, a new instance should be launched for every intent, but it isn't.

Comment: I'm accepting the answer because it helped me dig in the right direction, but the official documentation still confuses me. I can't understand why "standard" launchmode doesn't' work here.

Comment: In general, what the documentation says is true. However, there are some points that are described elsewhere in the documentation. If you launch an Intent with `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` (which is probably being done here when you use the SHARE action from YouTube), and the Activity being launched is the root activity of an existing task (which it is, in this case), then the existing task is brought to the foreground only (and nothing else happens). This is documented here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK

Comment: This is what happens, for example, when you have your app in the bacground and you click on the icon for your app on the HOME screen (or select your app from the list of recent tasks). Android launches the app by creating an `Intent` for the root Activity and setting `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`. If the app isn't already running, it will be started, but if it is already running, you don't want to have it started again. You just want Android to bring the existing task to the foreground. I hope this is clearer for you now.

Comment: You could make this work better (and have more control about exactly how it works) by creating a separate `Activity` for the SEND action. You have made this complicated by mixing the SEND action with the root (LAUNCHER) action.

Comment: In my real scenario, I'm actually doing this. And the trick with singleTop, doesn't work in that case, but you've set me on the right track, I'm digging through launchmodes, and intent flags now. Could make it work in a first test by using "singleTask" but the docs say, not to do this unless you know what you're doing, which I don't really yet. Thanks for your help anyway. If I can't figure this out there'll be a follow up question.

Comment: In general you don't want to use launch modes "singleINstance" or "singleTask". These aren't for general use and you will make more problems than you solve. This shouldn't be a difficult problem to solve.