# SharedActivity.getIntent beyond OnCreate

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey

I'm working on an Android project which is supposed to get a string from another application via shared activity.

If the application is not active, I'm able to get the getIntent info whether from the OnCreate or from a button click. But when the application is already launched and in background, if the other application send another intent, I get the same intent that was in the OnCreate and not the new one.

Thanks

```
  Var
  Intent: JIntent;
  S: String;
begin

  Try

    Intent := SharedActivity.getIntent;


    if Intent  Nil Then
    Begin

      if TJIntent.JavaClass.ACTION_SEND.equals(intent.getAction) Then
      Begin

        S := JStringToString(intent.getStringExtra(TJIntent.JavaClass.EXTRA_TEXT));

      End;

    End;

  Except
    On E: Exception Do
    ShowMessage(E.Message);
  End;
```

Remy,

Thank you for your reply.

I tried everything (I think) and could'nt make it work. That's what I did:

I followed Brian's explanation by the letter, built a new .Jar file without the NFC calls and it failed at launch, that's the log from DDMS:

> 05-13 11:46:49.101: E/AndroidRuntime(16597):
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.blong.IntentTest/com.blong.nfc.NativeActivitySubclass}:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   "com.blong.nfc.NativeActivitySubclass" on path: DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/data/app/com.blong.IntentTest-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.blong.IntentTest-1/lib/arm,
>   /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]

So I rebuit the .Jar file from the original .Java file which includes the NFC and it didn't work either. When the app is in background and launched from a new intent, the application shows a black screen and freezes as soon as it comes up, the last thing was to comment everything in the onNewIntent procedure and the result was the same - black screen.

Then I realized that the app was launched twice when having another app sending intent, and both instances freeze, see picture.

[image]

I tried also to add singletop to the launchmode as suggested in ci_ post  - no success.

How can I make such a simple thing to work?

Thanks

Comment: give us a peace of code to see your calls

Comment: I've asked a similar question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28969169/receiving-consecutive-send-intents-brings-app-back-to-the-front-but-does-not-up not sure if it's close enough for a duplicate.

Comment: @ci_ How do I implement OnNewIntent() ?

Answer (score 1):

`Activity.getIntent()` returns the `Intent` that launched the calling process.  It is not updated if the process receives a new `Intent` while already running.  Android has an `onNewIntent` event for that purpose, but unfortunately FireMonkey does not expose that event.  However, there is a workaround, as described in the following blog:

[Using NFC in Delphi XE7 Android apps | Receiving new intents at runtime](http://blong.com/Articles/DelphiXE7NFC/NFC.htm#ReceivingIntents)

> The steps required for responding to a new intent are as follows:
>
> - inherit from the standard FireMonkey Java native activity class in Java code (a .java file), implementing an onNewIntent() method that calls into a native method, which we'll implement in Delphi
> - compile the Java code into a compiled Java class file (a .class file) using javac.exe, referencing the Embarcadero compiled Java activity class
> - add the Java class file to a Java archive (a .jar file) using jar.exe
> - add the .jar file to the Delphi project
> - in the Delphi code declare a native JNI method that will be called by the Java code
> - orchestrate a thread switch from the Java UI thread to the FireMonkey thread, morphing any JNI parameter objects into Java Bridge wrapper objects along the way

The blog goes into detail of each step, showing the Java and Delphi code necessarily to implement it.