# Notification does not open the fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-intent, android-notifications

I created a Notification and I want it to open a Fragment when clicked. It works in general, but when I have another Fragment open in my application at the time, it does not work.

For example, I have two Fragments: `NoticiaFrag` and `EventoFrag`. If I open my application and open the `NoticiaFrag` after pressing the home button of the device to minimize the application and receiving a notification to `EventoFrag`, when I click the notification opens `NoticiaFrag` and not `EventoFrag`.

To make this work I need close the application with the back button. After the application closes it works fine. I think I need to reopen the application when I click the Notification, but I don't know how.

The method that opens the Fragments from the Notification is in `CustomDrawerLayout` and called `openFrag()`.

How can I solve this issue?

**Notification**

```
public class SendNotification {

     public SendNotification(Context context, String title, String tickerText, String message, String url) {
            NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            PendingIntent contentIntent;

            Intent intent = new Intent(context, CustomDrawerLayout.class);

            Bundle bd = new Bundle();
            bd.putString("url", url);
            intent.putExtras(bd);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |  Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

            contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

            NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo)
                    .setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION))
                    .setTicker(tickerText)
                    .setContentTitle(title)
                    .setShowWhen(true)
                    .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                    .setContentText(message);

            mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);

            Notification notification = mBuilder.build();
            notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
            notification.vibrate = new long[]{150, 300, 150, 600};
            mNotificationManager.notify(AndroidSystemUtil.randInt(), notification);        
        }
    }
```

**Manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="br.com.ferpapps.santaluzapp" >

    <!--Internet -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <!--GCM Permissions -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <permission      android:name=".permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name=".permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"></uses-permission>
    <!---->

    <!-- permissoes extra -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>


    <application
        android:name=".cv.CustomVolleySingleton"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        >

        <!-- GCM -->
        <receiver
            android:name=".push.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <category android:name="br.com.ferpapps" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <service
            android:name=".push.GcmIntentService" >
        </service>
        <!-- close GCM -->


        <activity
            android:name=".act.SplashView"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".menu.CustomDrawerLayout"/>
        <activity android:name=".act.AreaAlunoMainActivity" />

    </application>
</manifest>
```

**ActionBarActivity**

```
public class CustomDrawerLayout extends ActionBarActivity implements OnItemClickListener{
    private ActionBar ab;
    private DrawerLayout dl;
    private ListView lv;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle tg;
    private LinearLayout navdrawer;

    private List<ItensListView> fragments;
    private CharSequence tl; //titulo principal
    private CharSequence tlf; //titulo fragment

    public static final String APP_NAME = "App";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_custom_drawerlayout);
        getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(R.color.action_bar)));
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
        getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.actionbar_custom);

        init();

        openFrag();
    }

    private void openFrag(){
        //verifica notificacao e abre o fragment correspondente
        String url = getIntent().getStringExtra("url") != null ? getIntent().getStringExtra("url") : null;
        Log.i("URL_NOTIFICACAO->", url != null ? url : "");
        if(url != null) {
            //Open By Notification
            if (url.equals("Noticias")) {
                selectedItem(0);
            } else if (url.equals("Eventos")) {
                selectedItem(1);
            } else if (url.equals("Tarefas") ||
                    url.equals("Advertencias") ||
                    url.equals("Agendas")) {
                Log.i("Notificacao", url);
                Log.i("LOGADO NA SESSION", SessionUsuario.isLogged(this) + "");

                if(SessionUsuario.isLogged(this)){
                    Log.i("Notificao Logado", "esta logado na area do aluno");
                    FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    Fragment frag = AreaAlunoFrag.newInstance();
                    frag.getArguments().putString("url", url);
                    ft.replace(R.id.fl, frag);
                    ft.addToBackStack(APP_NAME);
                    ft.commit();
                }
            }
        }else{
            Log.i("ENTREI FIRST FRAG->","ENTREEIII");
            //if(savedInstanceState == null){
                selectedItem(0);
            //}
        }
    }

    private void init(){
        //actionbar
        onConfigActionBar();
        //listview
        configItensListView();
        //drawerlayout
        dl = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.dl);
        navdrawer = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.navdrawer);
        //listview
        lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lv);               
        lv.setAdapter(new DrawerLayoutListViewAdapter(this, fragments));
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        //drawerlayout
        //dl = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.dl);
        //mDrawerRelativeLayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
        //actionbardrawertoggle
        tg = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, dl, R.drawable.ic_launcher, R.string.drawer_open){
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                ab.setTitle(tl);
                supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View view) {
                ab.setTitle(tlf);
                supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        };
        dl.setDrawerListener(tg);
        tl = tlf = getTitle();
    }

    /** ativa actionbar e botao home na action bar */
    private void onConfigActionBar(){
        ab = getSupportActionBar();
        ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        ab.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        tg.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    /** necessario */
    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        tg.syncState();
    }


     @Override
     public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
         if (tg.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
                return true;
         }
         return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
     }

     /** necessario */
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.custom_drawer_layout, menu);
        return true;
    }

    /** necessario */
    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        boolean status = dl.isDrawerOpen(navdrawer);
        //menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(!status);
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,long id) {
        Log.i("POSITION->", position + "");
        selectedItem(position);     
    }

    /** seleciona o fragment q sera usado */
    private void selectedItem(int position){
        FragmentTransaction ft;
        Fragment frag;
        switch (position){
            case 0:
                ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                frag = NoticiaFrag.newInstance();
                ft.replace(R.id.fl, frag);
                ft.addToBackStack(APP_NAME);
                ft.commit();
                break;
            case 1:
                ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                frag = EventoFrag.newInstance();
                ft.replace(R.id.fl, frag);
                ft.addToBackStack(APP_NAME);
                ft.commit();
                break;
            case 2:
                ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                frag = LoginFrag.newInstance();
                ft.replace(R.id.fl, frag);
                ft.addToBackStack(APP_NAME);
                ft.commit();
                break;
            case 3:
                ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                frag = ContatoFrag.newInstance();
                ft.replace(R.id.fl, frag);
                ft.addToBackStack(APP_NAME);
                ft.commit();
                break;
            case 4:
                ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                frag = CompartilhaFrag.newInstance();
                ft.replace(R.id.fl, frag);
                ft.addToBackStack(APP_NAME);
                ft.commit();
                break;
            case 5:
                ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                frag = SobreFrag.newInstance();
                ft.replace(R.id.fl, frag);
                ft.addToBackStack(APP_NAME);
                ft.commit();
                break;
            default:
                closeApp();
                break;
        }
        lv.setItemChecked(position, true);
        setCustomTitle(fragments.get(position).getTexto());
        dl.closeDrawer(navdrawer);
    }

    /** define o titulo da actionbar */
    private void setCustomTitle(String title){
        //SpannableString s = new SpannableString(title);
       // s.setSpan(new TypefaceSpan(this, BatalhaConfigs.FONT), 0, s.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        //ab.setTitle(s);
        //tl = s;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        //if(getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0){
        //    getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate();
       // }else{
            super.onBackPressed();
        //}
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResumeFragments() {
        super.onResumeFragments();
    }

    /** Configura o List com as informacoes **/
    private void configItensListView(){
        fragments = new ArrayList<ItensListView>();
        //define
        ItensListView itens0 = new ItensListView("Noticias", R.drawable.setavermelha);
        ItensListView itens1 = new ItensListView("Eventos", R.drawable.setavermelha);
        ItensListView itens2 = new ItensListView("Área do Aluno", R.drawable.setavermelha);
        ItensListView itens3 = new ItensListView("Contato", R.drawable.setavermelha);
        ItensListView itens4 = new ItensListView("Redes Sociais", R.drawable.setavermelha);
        ItensListView itens5 = new ItensListView("Sobre", R.drawable.setavermelha);
        ItensListView itens6 = new ItensListView("Sair", R.drawable.setavermelha);

        //add
        fragments.add(itens0);
        fragments.add(itens1);
        fragments.add(itens2);
        fragments.add(itens3);
        fragments.add(itens4);
        fragments.add(itens5);
        fragments.add(itens6);

        //AreaAlunoFrag
    }

    private void closeApp(){
        System.exit(0);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState, PersistableBundle outPersistentState) {
        //super.onSaveInstanceState(outState, outPersistentState);
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().commitAllowingStateLoss();
    }

    private void removeAllFrags(){
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        for(int x = 0; x < fm.getBackStackEntryCount(); x++){
            //getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(fm.findFragmentById(x)).commit();
            fm.popBackStackImmediate();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        new SendProjectId(getApplicationContext());
        super.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        PushControl.setIsVisible(true);
        new SendProjectId(getApplicationContext());
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        PushControl.setIsVisible(false);        
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        PushControl.setIsVisible(false);
        //removeAllFrags();
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        PushControl.setIsVisible(false);
        super.onDestroy();
        CustomVolleySingleton.getInstance().cancelPendingRequests(CustomVolleySingleton.TAG);
    }

}
```

**Update CustomDrawerLayout and Manifest - It works fine.**

**CustomDrawerLayout**

```
public class CustomDrawerLayout extends ActionBarActivity implements OnItemClickListener{
    private ActionBar ab;
    private DrawerLayout dl;
    private ListView lv;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle tg;
    private LinearLayout navdrawer;

    private List<ItensListView> fragments;
    private CharSequence tl; //titulo principal
    private CharSequence tlf; //titulo fragment

    public static final String APP_NAME = "App";
    private static String URL_NOTIFICATION = "";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_custom_drawerlayout);
        getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(R.color.action_bar)));
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
        getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.actionbar_custom);

        init();

        if(savedInstanceState == null){
           selectedItem(0);
        }
    }

    /** open fragment by notification */
    private void openFragByNotification(){

        if(!URL_NOTIFICATION.isEmpty()) {
            //Open By Notification
            if (URL_NOTIFICATION.equals("Noticias")) {
                selectedItem(0);
            } else if (URL_NOTIFICATION.equals("Eventos")) {
                selectedItem(1);
            } else if (URL_NOTIFICATION.equals("Tarefas") ||
                    URL_NOTIFICATION.equals("Advertencias") ||
                    URL_NOTIFICATION.equals("Agendas")) {
                Log.i("Notificacao", URL_NOTIFICATION);
                Log.i("LOGADO NA SESSION", SessionUsuario.isLogged(this) + "");

                if(SessionUsuario.isLogged(this)){
                    Log.i("Notificao Logado", "esta logado na area do aluno");
                    FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    Fragment frag = AreaAlunoFrag.newInstance();
                    frag.getArguments().putString("url", URL_NOTIFICATION);
                    ft.replace(R.id.fl, frag);
                    ft.addToBackStack(APP_NAME);
                    ft.commit();
                }
            }
        }
    }


    private void init(){
        //actionbar
        onConfigActionBar();
        //listview
        configItensListView();
        //drawerlayout
        dl = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.dl);
        navdrawer = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.navdrawer);
        //listview
        lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lv);               
        lv.setAdapter(new DrawerLayoutListViewAdapter(this, fragments));
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        //drawerlayout
        //dl = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.dl);
        //mDrawerRelativeLayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
        //actionbardrawertoggle
        tg = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, dl, R.drawable.ic_launcher, R.string.drawer_open){
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                ab.setTitle(tl);
                supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View view) {
                ab.setTitle(tlf);
                supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        };
        dl.setDrawerListener(tg);
        tl = tlf = getTitle();
    }

    /** ativa actionbar e botao home na action bar */
    private void onConfigActionBar(){
        ab = getSupportActionBar();
        ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        ab.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        tg.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    /** necessario */
    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        tg.syncState();
    }


     @Override
     public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
         if (tg.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
                return true;
         }
         return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
     }



     /** necessario */
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.custom_drawer_layout, menu);
        return true;
    }


    /** necessario */
    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        boolean status = dl.isDrawerOpen(navdrawer);
        //menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(!status);
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,long id) {
        Log.i("POSITION->", position + "");
        selectedItem(position);     
    }

    /** seleciona o fragment q sera usado */
    private void selectedItem(int position){
        FragmentTransaction ft;
        Fragment frag;
        switch (position){
            case 0:
                ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                frag = NoticiaFrag.newInstance();
                ft.replace(R.id.fl, frag);
                ft.addToBackStack(APP_NAME);
                ft.commit();
                break;
            case 1:
                ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                frag = EventoFrag.newInstance();
                ft.replace(R.id.fl, frag);
                ft.addToBackStack(APP_NAME);
                ft.commit();
                break;
            case 2:
                ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                frag = LoginFrag.newInstance();
                ft.replace(R.id.fl, frag);
                ft.addToBackStack(APP_NAME);
                ft.commit();
                break;
            case 3:
                ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                frag = ContatoFrag.newInstance();
                ft.replace(R.id.fl, frag);
                ft.addToBackStack(APP_NAME);
                ft.commit();
                break;
            case 4:
                ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                frag = CompartilhaFrag.newInstance();
                ft.replace(R.id.fl, frag);
                ft.addToBackStack(APP_NAME);
                ft.commit();
                break;
            case 5:
                ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                frag = SobreFrag.newInstance();
                ft.replace(R.id.fl, frag);
                ft.addToBackStack(APP_NAME);
                ft.commit();
                break;
            default:
                closeApp();
                break;

        }

        lv.setItemChecked(position, true);
        setCustomTitle(fragments.get(position).getTexto());
        dl.closeDrawer(navdrawer);
    }

    /** define o titulo da actionbar */
    private void setCustomTitle(String title){
        //SpannableString s = new SpannableString(title);
       // s.setSpan(new TypefaceSpan(this, BatalhaConfigs.FONT), 0, s.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        //ab.setTitle(s);
        //tl = s;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        //if(getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0){
        //    getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate();
       // }else{
            super.onBackPressed();

        //}
    }


    @Override
    protected void onResumeFragments() {
        super.onResumeFragments();
    }

    /** Configura o List com as informacoes **/
    private void configItensListView(){
        fragments = new ArrayList<ItensListView>();
        //define
        ItensListView itens0 = new ItensListView("Noticias", R.drawable.setavermelha);
        ItensListView itens1 = new ItensListView("Eventos", R.drawable.setavermelha);
        ItensListView itens2 = new ItensListView("Área do Aluno", R.drawable.setavermelha);
        ItensListView itens3 = new ItensListView("Contato", R.drawable.setavermelha);
        ItensListView itens4 = new ItensListView("Redes Sociais", R.drawable.setavermelha);
        ItensListView itens5 = new ItensListView("Sobre", R.drawable.setavermelha);
        ItensListView itens6 = new ItensListView("Sair", R.drawable.setavermelha);

        //add
        fragments.add(itens0);
        fragments.add(itens1);
        fragments.add(itens2);
        fragments.add(itens3);
        fragments.add(itens4);
        fragments.add(itens5);
        fragments.add(itens6);


        //AreaAlunoFrag

    }

    private void closeApp(){
        System.exit(0);
    }


    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState, PersistableBundle outPersistentState) {
        //super.onSaveInstanceState(outState, outPersistentState);
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().commitAllowingStateLoss();

    }

    private void removeAllFrags(){
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        for(int x = 0; x < fm.getBackStackEntryCount(); x++){
            //getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(fm.findFragmentById(x)).commit();
            fm.popBackStackImmediate();
        }
    }


    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        URL_NOTIFICATION = intent.getStringExtra("url");
        Log.i("URL_NOTIFICATION", URL_NOTIFICATION);
        super.onNewIntent(intent);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        new SendProjectId(getApplicationContext());
        super.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        PushControl.setIsVisible(true);
        new SendProjectId(getApplicationContext());
        openFragByNotification();
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        PushControl.setIsVisible(false);
        URL_NOTIFICATION = "";
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        PushControl.setIsVisible(false);
        URL_NOTIFICATION = "";
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        PushControl.setIsVisible(false);
        super.onDestroy();
        CustomVolleySingleton.getInstance().cancelPendingRequests(CustomVolleySingleton.TAG);
    }


}
```

**Manifest**

```
<activity android:name=".menu.CustomDrawerLayout" android:launchMode="singleTop"/>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that Android by default doesn't deliver a new `Intent` to an `Activity` that is already running. If you close your app via the back button, the `Activity` is destroyed and the next time `startActivity()` is called a new instance is created and the new `Intent` delivered. If you leave the `Activity` via the home button, the `Activity` is not destroyed. When you call `startActivity()` in this case, the already running instance of the `Activity` is brought to the foreground, but a new `Intent` is *not* delivered.

To change this behaviour you can define your activity in the manifest with `launchMode="singleTop"`:

```
<activity
    ...
    android:launchMode="singleTop"
    ...
>
</activity>
```

In this case Android will deliver a new `Intent` via `onNewIntent()`, which you can [override](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-tw/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onNewIntent(android.content.Intent)):

> This is called for activities that set launchMode to "singleTop" in their package, or if a client used the FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP flag when calling startActivity(Intent). In either case, when the activity is re-launched while at the top of the activity stack instead of a new instance of the activity being started, onNewIntent() will be called on the existing instance with the Intent that was used to re-launch it.

Just noticed the flags you're passing into your `Intent`. In that case you probably just have to override `onNewIntent()` in your `Activity`.

I've run into this problem myself before and asked a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28969169/receiving-consecutive-send-intents-brings-app-back-to-the-front-but-does-not-up). There's some more background in that question, the accepted answer, and the comments.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I did update with solution what you suggested and works fine. I updated my post also with solution. Thanks again.

Comment: Hi. I have a new problem now. When I close app with button back, does stop works and I need click icon to open app to works again, by notification doesn't works, I think that notification doesn`t create a new task because it I need click icon to open my app again. Can you help me ?

Comment: You changed a lot of stuff in the code around, so I'm not 100% sure, but it looks like you don't set `URL_NOTIFICATION` in `onCreate()`, so when you're calling `openFragByNotification()` from `onResume()` it's empty. Maybe the misunderstanding is that `onNewIntent()` is _only_ called if an instance of the `Activity` already exists, not when a new instance is created.